# 404 error while trying to install WINE

Tags: wine, emulation

I tried to install WINE onto ubuntu from which I have just downloaded, but It gives me a strange message after that.

`Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glib2.0/libglib2.0-0_2.31.14-0ubuntu1_i386.deb 404  Not Found` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Wine via the Ubuntu Software Center: [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/wine).